# spring security rest plugin error creating bean

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Im trying to integrate spring security rest plugin into our webapp. Which already have spring security plugin installed.

I added these to the build config

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC3", {
    excludes: 'spring-security-core'
}
```

Now Im getting this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestOauthController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityRestRestOauthService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
```

I have tried doing a grails clean, compile. Still the error persists.

Comment: Possibly you also needs the next plugin `compile ":spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"
compile(":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC3") {
    excludes 'spring-security-core'
}
```